# utf-8 coding in python gui

Tags: python, user-interface, encoding, utf-8, pyqt4

I have simple app with English and Hungarian language. All localizables are in separate modul -localizable.py, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
...
if language == "hun":
    LOGIN_LABEL_USERNAME_STR                    = 'Felhasználó'
    LOGIN_LABEL_PASSWORD_STR                    = 'Jelszó'
elif language == "eng":    
    LOGIN_LABEL_USERNAME_STR                    = 'Username'
    LOGIN_LABEL_PASSWORD_STR                    = 'Password'
```

But when I use Hungerian language in loginDialog.py:

```
import localizable
...
...
loginLayout.addRow(localizable.LOGIN_LABEL_USERNAME_STR, QtGui.QLineEdit())
loginLayout.addRow(localizable.LOGIN_LABEL_PASSWORD_STR, QtGui.QLineEdit())
...
```

I get  `FelhasznÃ¡lÃ³` and  `JelszÃ³` instead `Felhasználó` and `Jelszó`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `unicode` objects in your `localizable` module, instead of bytestrings with no encoding?

```
if language == "hun":
    LOGIN_LABEL_USERNAME_STR                    = u'Felhasználó'
    LOGIN_LABEL_PASSWORD_STR                    = u'Jelszó'
```

This has the intended effect for me.

You also might want to consider using the [built-in functions](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QTranslator.html) for this provided by Qt.

Comment: Tnx, that's it, but I've left coding utf-8 because without it I get this **SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:~\localizable.py on line 49, but no encoding declared**

Comment: @Aleksandar: You need to both specify the source encoding (in python 2; py3k assumes UTF-8) *and* mark them as Unicode strings (also in python 2; py3k strings are unicode rather than bytestrings).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your source file is UTF8-encoded, meaning the string `Felhasználó` is represented as the bytes `46 65 6c 68 61 73 7a 6e c3 a1 6c c3 b3` in the source code file.  If you print this byte array out as if they were in LATIN-1-encoding, you will get `FelhasznÃ¡lÃ³`.

Further, you pass these UTF-8 encoded bytes along as just a plain string to Qt, which seems to assume it is in LATIN-1 encoding.  This means instead of assuming the bytes `c3 b3` (`Ã³`) are code for `ó` as it would be in UTF8, it assumes `c3` is plain `Ã` and `b3` is `³` which is the case for LATIN1.

frb's answer is the correct way to do this, because by sending a `unicode` string instead, you have done all the interpretation and leave no ambiguity for Qt.